# How to unique my data that are stored in an object which are stored in a vector?

Tags: c++, object, vector, duplicates

I want to create a method to eliminate duplicates from a text file.

Edit: Why am i getting downvoted ? It's not like I didn't search through the web before asking.

For example, the data in the text file:

```
Fruits:Edible:Inedible
Apple:5:10
Apple:1:2
Pear:5:1
Orange:20:1
Pear:5:1
Apple:5:10
Orange:1:20
Orange:20:1
```

I have a class of apple, orange, pear according to this example. Using the class, I have created 3 different object vector to store them in, using set methods.

For example if `Apple` is detected:

```
Apple.setedible(Edible);
Apple.setinedible(Inedible);
```

I can currently store them nicely into their object vectors which will result in this:

```
In Apple vector:
5:10
1:2
5:10

In Orange Vector:
20:1
1:20
20:1

In Pear Vector:
5:1
5:1
```

I want to eliminate the duplicates base on `edible` and `inedible` and I have no idea on how am I going to eliminate them which will result me in:

```
In Apple vector:
5:10
1:2

In Orange Vector:
20:1
1:20

In Pear Vector:
5:1
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want as type for `5:10` or `1:2` ? Is it a string or a couple of integers ? I suppose it's a string for my example.

You should use a `std::map< std::string , std::set<std::string> >` to store your data. Then you can add it like this example with each string unique for each fruit :

```
std::map< std::string , std::set<std::string> > data;
data["Apple"].insert("5:10");
data["Apple"].insert("1:2");
data["Apple"].insert("5:10"); // Nothing is inserted here, already exists
```

Comment: it reads in from a text file, so at the start it's a string and i convert it to int before setting it into the object

Comment: and for now, i am storing them as an int variable, without the `:`

Comment: I did thought of using `maps` or `sets`. However, all tutorials i have seen so far on the web are base on a type, `string`, `int`, etc etc, none of the examples are base on objects. And to be specific, to be base on 2 of the variables in the object

Comment: @Zac: So you may replace `std::set<std::string>` by `std::set<std::pair<int, int>>` (or your own structure with `operator <` to replace the pair).

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, i have just replace that, but now i am unable to `cout` them for testing, before i change, i was using `applevector[i].getEdible()` and `applevector[i].getInedible()` to do checking

Comment: And, thanks for the replying, your ideas and help allow me to continue with my work, thanks from the bottom of my heart.